# Update more the 500000 rows value in mysql

Tags: mysql, laravel

Right now I have 2 tables users and user_purchase_stocks.

1. users table structure

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | user1 |
| 2 | user2 |
| 3 | user3 |
| 4 | user4 |

2)user_purchase_stocks structure

| id | user_id | stock |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 50 |
| 2 | 2 | 40 |
| 3 | 2 | 35 |
| 4 | 3 | 70 |
| 5 | 3 | 170 |
| 6 | 1 | 20 |
| 7 | 2 | 30 |
| 8 | 4 | 15 |

Now I am adding one more column (total_purchase_stock) in the user's table. so I need the total stock of each user and store in it's a row. For example, user1 purchases 50 + 20 so total value save in user1 is 70.

But the problem is users table have more than 500000 rows and in user_purchased_stocks have 20 00000 rows, so what will be the best solution for me to get the total in user table

Extra: I am using laravel framework maybe you have a solution in laravel. so please help me.

Comment: I don't understand why the number of rows presents a problem.

Comment: @Strawberry it's taking to much time to update

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query - in addition, questions about query performance always require the EXPLAIN for the given query

Comment: Create a triggers which recalculates `users.total` on each `purchase` table data change. Then simply perform fake update for one purchase row for each user. You may do this by chunks in SP. *it's taking to much time to update* Update time makes no sense for one-time task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do this all in mysql

First run

```
ALTER TABLE  
users ADD COLUMN total_purchase_stock BIGINT DEFAULT 0;
```

then run

```
UPDATE 
users u INNER JOIN (SELECT  user_id , SUM(stock) SUMStock FROM user_purchase_stocks  GROUP By user_id) st ON u.user_id = st.user_id
SET u.total_purchase_stock = u.total_purchase_stock + st.SUMStock;
```

If it takes to long, you must run it on a command prompt(via ssh), so that it doesn't run in a time out. PHP has always a timeout.

Then add a  trigger so that the total_purchase_stock   gets automatically upodated when a new row is inserted. If you update the table you need also use atrigger to get that.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER after_user_purchase_stocks_insert
AFTER INSERT
ON user_purchase_stocks   FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.stock > 0 AND NEW.stock IS NOT NULL THEN
    UPDATE 
    users SET total_purchase_stock  = total_purchase_stock  + NEW.stock;
    END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

If you are worried about loosing data, add first the column add the trigger and then  run the update

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is **Chunking Results**

Your application may run out of memory if you attempt to load tens of thousands of Eloquent records via the `all` or `get` methods. Instead of using these methods, the `chunk` method may be used to process large numbers of models more efficiently.

The `chunk` method will retrieve a subset of Eloquent models, passing them to a closure for processing. Since only the current `chunk` of Eloquent models is retrieved at a time, the chunk method will provide significantly reduced memory usage when working with a large number of models:

```
use App\Models\User;

User::chunk(200, function ($users) {
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        //
    }
});
```

The first argument passed to the `chunk` method is the number of records you wish to receive per "chunk". The closure passed as the second argument will be invoked for each chunk that is retrieved from the database. A database query will be executed to retrieve each chunk of records passed to the closure.

If you are filtering the results of the `chunk` method based on a column that you will also be updating while iterating over the results, you should use the `chunkById` method. Using the `chunk` method in these scenarios could lead to unexpected and inconsistent results. Internally, the `chunkById` method will always retrieve models with an id column greater than the last model in the previous chunk:

```
User::where('name', 'John')
        ->chunkById(200, function ($users) {
            $users->each->update(['total_purchase_stock' => 562]);
        }, $column = 'id');
```